# Pyopengl - how to dispose old textures and glGenLists?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am using glGenLists like this:

```
my_list = glGenLists(1)
glNewList(array_list, GL_COMPILE)
# some OpenGL instructions go here
glEndList()
```

In similar way I am using textues:

```
my_texture = glGenTextures(1)
```

If I understand correctly, the textures and lists are stored at GPU. How can I dispose them when I do not need them anymore?

Is enough to ovewrite the pointers (`my_list = False`). Or do I need to tell to pyopengl that I do not need them anymore somehow manually?

Comment: [`glDeleteTextures`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDeleteTextures.xhtml)? [`glDeleteLists`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glDeleteLists.xml)? There is a glDelete* for each glGen* (and they are also linked on the bottom of each documentation page.

Comment: @BDL Excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a glDelete* that deallocates a previously allocated resource for each glGen*.

[glDeleteTexture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDeleteTextures.xhtml)

[glDeleteLists](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glDeleteLists.xml)